# How to add today's Date via a ng-model to my date input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to show today's date in my date input:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="data.date">
```

Here is my JS Code:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.date = new Date().toDateString();
```

But the result is only:
[image]

What did I wrong?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? The type=date format should be working on angular 1.3 or newer. Otherwise you might have to settle for a displaying empty date input (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r1s83ev5/2/) or using a custom directive (https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `input[type='date']` , but format data must be  a valid ISO date string (yyyy-MM-dd)

```
<input type="date" ng-model="data.date">
```

and code

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.date = new Date();
```

or convert today's date into a readable string

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.date">
```

then code

```
 $scope.data = {};
 $scope.data.date = new Date().toDateString();
```

Comment: The first way is not owrking for me. And the sceond is not a valid way bacause I want to make it easy for the user to select the date.

Comment: Why the first way is not working for you? Let's look at the angularjs manual about a date: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D. Pay attention to a phrase "must be a valid ISO date format (yyyy-MM-dd)"

Comment: And if you use `toDateString()` that you convert Date to String format and how result it doesn't work with `input[type=date]`

Answer (score 0):

Html input:

```
[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
[(ngModel)]="stock.date"
```

TypeScript code to get `sysdate` with `ngModel`:

```
 padTo2Digits(num: number) {
    return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  }
  const d = new Date();
  const days = this.padTo2Digits(d.getDate());
  const months = this.padTo2Digits(d.getMonth() + 1);
  this.stock.date=d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + months + '-' + days;
```